# Why cant access name space Windows::Phone::UI::Input

Tags: c++-winrt

Using Blank winrt template project

Does not recognize winrt/Windows.Phone.UI.Input.h

meaning no namespace Windows.Phone.UI.Input.

trying to use class HardwareButtons

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Are you targeting Windows phone 8.0 (VS 2012), Windows phone 8.1 (VS 2013), or Universal Windows Platform for Windows 10 Mobile (VS 2015/2017)?

Comment: I am targeting Windows 10 x64 and Arm. Converting existing C# App using HardwareButtons into c++-Winrt. IF all else fails its guarded by ApiInformation::IsTypePresent for phone API.

Comment: Have you added reference of Windows Mobile Extensions?

Comment: thanks, Just tried that no luck, still cant see using namespace Windows::Phone::UI::Input which contains HardwareButton---------------------------------Also added #include #include "winrt/Windows.Phone.UI.Input.h", but header not in scope either.